# subset values in a column that are not present in another column in r

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, unique, multiple-columns

I'm trying to subset my data so that I have three new data frames:

1. a data frame containing competitors in the comp01_name column (col 12)that are not in the comp02_name column (col 17)
2. a data frame containing competitors who only appear in column 17, but not in column 12
3. a data frame with competitors who appear in both columns

I checked beforehand how many competitors I should expect to see in the first two data frames, and the numbers (see code) differ from the actual number of rows seen in the data frames. Is there something wrong with my code? Why am I getting differing number of rows? How do I fix it?

master.treeDQ2.1 should only have 2037 rows, but has 2141 rows in the data frame

master.treeDQ2.1 should only have 1476 rows, but has 3750 rows

Now i'm skeptical that master.treeDQboth also has the incorrect number of rows

```
master.treeDQ2 = read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bandcar/Examples/main/master.treeDQ.edited_draft6.csv')

# check for competitors in comp02 that are not in comp01
length(setdiff(master.treeDQ2$comp02_name, master.treeDQ2$comp01_name)) #1476 ppl are in comp02 that are not in comp01

# check for competitors in comp01 that are not in comp02
length(setdiff(master.treeDQ2$comp01_name, master.treeDQ2$comp02_name))
# 2037 are in comp01, but not in comp02

# subset competitors who only appear in comp01 but not comp02
master.treeDQ2.1 = master.treeDQ2[!(master.treeDQ2$comp02_name %in% master.treeDQ2$comp01_name),]

# subset competitors who only appear in comp02 but not comp01
master.treeDQ2.2 = master.treeDQ2[!(master.treeDQ2$comp01_name %in% master.treeDQ2$comp02_name),]

# subset for competitors present in both columns
master.treeDQboth = master.treeDQ2[master.treeDQ2$comp01_name %in% master.treeDQ2$comp02_name,]
```

Comment: You may want to check out the dplyr mutating join functions: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate-joins.html and https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter-joins.html  You can join a dataframe with itself.  So in your case doing that and setting the join conditions comparing the values in column 12 with the values of column 17 of the dataframe joined with itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your results are correct. It is your expectations that are slightly awry, because the names in your columns are not unique. You say:

> master.treeDQ2.1 should only have 1476 rows, but has 3750 rows

However, there should be 1476 *unique* competitors in `comp02_name`, rather than 1476 rows. This is the case.

```r
length(unique(master.treeDQ2.1$comp02_name)) # 1476
length(unique(master.treeDQ2.1$comp02_name)) == 
    length(setdiff(master.treeDQ2$comp02_name, master.treeDQ2$comp01_name)) # TRUE
```

However, this line will not necessarily do what your comment says as there may be competitors in `comp02_name` who are not in `comp01_name`.

```r
# subset for competitors present in both columns
master.treeDQboth = master.treeDQ2[master.treeDQ2$comp01_name %in% master.treeDQ2$comp02_name,]
```

I am not exactly sure what you want but it seems to me it must be either:

1. Keep rows where the competitor in `comp01_name` OR `comp02_name` is in both columns. There are some competitors in each column that are not in both columns but you have all rows for the competitors that are in both columns, even when they're matched against competitors that only appear in one column. Your code does this for when a competitor in `comp01_name` appears in both columns and is matched against someone in `comp02_name` who does not - but not the other way around.

```r
in_both_columns <- intersect(master.treeDQ2$comp01_name, master.treeDQ2$comp02_name)

master.treeDQboth <- master.treeDQ2[
    (master.treeDQ2$comp01_name %in% in_both_columns) |
        (master.treeDQ2$comp02_name %in% in_both_columns),
]
```

2. Keep only rows where the competitor in `comp01_name` AND `comp02_name` is in both columns. All competitors in the data frame appear in both columns but you lose the rows for the competitors when they were matched against those who do not appear in both columns.

```r
in_both_columns <- intersect(master.treeDQ2$comp01_name, master.treeDQ2$comp02_name)

master.treeDQboth <- master.treeDQ2[
    (master.treeDQ2$comp01_name %in% in_both_columns) &
        (master.treeDQ2$comp02_name %in% in_both_columns),
]
```

Comment: Thank you! For the data frame that should have competitors who are in both columns, what is not correct? I thought `master.treeDQ2$comp01_name %in% master.treeDQ2$comp02_name` tells r to get competitors who appear in both columns?

Comment: I have edited my reply to explain a bit better. I also agree with the comment which says this would be easier if you used `dplyr`.

Comment: Okay, so in master.treeDQboth, I want to keep only competitors who appear in both comp01_name AND in comp02_name. So I tried the code you posted and tested out a few names. There were still several people who only appeared in one column, not both. I'll look into the dplyr method though.

Comment: I just tried using `filter`. I couldn't find how to use it in my specific case. It seems you can only use `filter` if you have a specific value